# Will suspend foil a "Cheesy" victory?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [The Cheese Stands Alone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9773) (or [Barren Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136048)) and destroy my other permanents somehow, will I win the game if I currently have a card suspended? Do that count as a card in play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will win.

> 702.61b A card is "suspended" if it's in the exile zone, has suspend, and has a time counter on it.

And a [ruling](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Exile) on exile:

> Exile is a gamezone **outside the field of play**. It was known as
>   "Removed from the game" before it was renamed in the wake of the Magic
>   2010 rules update.

Comment: It may be helpful to reference [Barren Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136048), which is the same card but has rulings and errata applied to it, since it's not an Unglued card.

Comment: @AlexP I knew there was a card like this, but didn't know its name. Thanks!

Comment: 406.1 defines a Exile as being a zone. Much more reliable and a ruling saying the same.

Comment: @Alex P, not quite the same card. BG checks for tokens on the battlefield, and TCSA doesn't.

Comment: @John, Tokens are NOT cards. 108.2 "[...] Tokens aren’t considered cards—even a card that represents a token isn’t considered a card for rules purposes." TCSA, as it stands, only checks for cards, not tokens (just like Bifurcate and Rishadan Pawnshop). If it weren't an Un card, it would very likely have been *changed* to check for tokens, but there has been no such change.

Comment: @John Yes, but note what you said yourself: Beasts of Bogardan had to be *explicitly* errata'd to say 'controls a white permanent' simply because 'permanent' and 'card' reference different things.  A card that hasn't had any errata applied to it (and TCSA is such a card) will play as printed, and the printed version of TCSA specifically talks about cards.  Whether that meant something different at the time or not is moot, because that is _still_ the current wording of the card.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, Unglued/Unhinged cards _do not receive errata_, because there's little reason to do so (they're not tournament-playable). Specific rules questions on silver-bordered cards go to Mark Rosewater's tumblr blog for official rulings.

Comment: @John, The difference with your example and the one in question is that changing "remove it from the game" to "exile it" does not change the effect, but changing "card on the battlefield" to "permanent" does. You can assume wording changes, but not functional changes.

Comment: @John, Care to back that up? I gave two examples (Bifurcate and Rishadan Pawnshop) that suggest otherwise.

Comment: @John, And no, you didn't say that three times. You actually said card is the old word for permanent, which is blatantly false. (e.g. "discard a card" has been in the game since alpha)

Comment: @John, No, that's not proof. Maybe if all instances were changed, but that's not the case. (And that's the third time I've mentioned that...) So again, can you back that up?

Comment: @John, I gave you two: Bifurcate and Rishadan Pawnshop. (Fourth time...)

Comment: @John, No, "card in play" became "nontoken permanent", and "creature card in play" became "nontoken creature". In neither case did "card in play" become "permanent". Read again

Comment: @John, Are you saying that creature tokens weren't creatures? Before, I was skeptical, but I distrust you. This is the second time you've shown a lack of basic rules knowledge. Are you going to back up your claim or are you going to keep deflecting?

Comment: @John, Re "Thus, they received different errata.", Duh. And according to you, the different errata should be "creature". It's not.

Comment: @John, Re "You have yet to provide a single example of an instance where the simple phrase 'card in play' was erratad to anything other than permanent." Rishadan Pawnshop (Fifth time...), and there's also Bifurcate which contradicts your actual claim rather than this strawman.

Comment: @John, Re "Proving that I am correct would actually require me to link to 20-30 cards at LEAST, which is really not feasible. " Uh, why would you link to cards? The rules aren't printed on cards. You seem to be arguing that widespread changes can't be functional changes. That's strike three. You've lost credibility. Your word concerning MTG is pure rumor to me unless backed.

Answer (score 3):

> will I win the game if I currently have a card suspended?

Yes.

> Do that count as a card in play?

No, "In play" is the old wording of "on the battlefield"<sup>[1]</sup>. Suspended cards aren't on the battlefield. They are found in the exile zone, so they do not prevent the ability from triggering or resolving.

> 702.61b A card is "suspended" if it's in the exile zone, has suspend, and has a time counter on it.

The ability checks the following two zones: The battlefield and your hand. Cards in libraries, in graveyards, on the stack, in the ante zone, in the command zone or in other players' hand do not prevent the ability from triggering or resolving.

---

Bonus:

You can even win with BG on the turn a suspended card "unsuspends". Simply place the suspended card's triggered ability on the stack first and BG's triggered ability on the stack second. BG's triggered ability will resolve before you have a chance to cast the suspended card.

---

1. [Reference](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/42a) (See *2A) Battlefield*.)